# How do I send the output of a function to a client in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a web interface based on NodeJS for my dumb printer. In my project, there is a feature which sends all the print jobs which are currently being processed. I obtain this information using lpstat (CUPS' status command). This executes whenever there is a GET request, as you can see here:

```
const express = require('express');
const { exec } = require('child_process')
var currentJobs;

function getCurrentJobs() {
    exec("lpstat", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            optimisedOutput = "An error occurred : " + `${error}`;
        } else if (stderr) {
            optimisedOutput = "An error occurred : " + `${stderr}`;
        }
        currentJobs = `${stdout}`
        console.log(currentJobs)
        return currentJobs;
    })
}

app.get('/currentJobs', (req, res) => {
    currentJobs = getCurrentJobs()
    currentJobs = JSON.stringify(currentJobs)
    res.status(200).send(currentJobs)
    console.log(currentJobs);
})
```

But, the variable `currentJobs` does not update. Instead, I get an undefined error and Postman does not show any outputs. It only shows the status code.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.
Edit: This will all be running on a Raspberry Pi 3 connected to the printer which is why I'm using CUPS.

Comment: Pass the res obj as parameter and use it instead of that return. Return in an callback has no meaning for the wrapping function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using exec as async execution, you either gonna need to change it to sync(prefer not to, for performance) or wrap it with promise, Ill show you the promise solution.

```js
const express = require('express');
const { exec } = require('child_process')
var currentJobs;

async function getCurrentJobs() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
        exec("lpstat", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
              optimisedOutput = "An error occurred : " + `${error}`;
          } else if (stderr) {
              optimisedOutput = "An error occurred : " + `${stderr}`;
          }
          currentJobs = `${stdout}`
          console.log(currentJobs)
          resolve(currentJobs);
      })
  })
}

app.get('/currentJobs', async (req, res) => {
    currentJobs = await getCurrentJobs()
    currentJobs = JSON.stringify(currentJobs)
    res.status(200).send(currentJobs)
    console.log(currentJobs);
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quickly! I just found one problem with the solution, the async keyword is supposed to be before the function declaration. But, otherwise, it works like a charm. It's 11:00 PM where I live, so I'll be able to get a good night's sleep today knowing there are no bugs in my code!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if you just promisify the function and use it as async/await as it will be much more readable and you are making a asynchronous call and expecting the behaviour of the code in a synchronous manner

```
const express = require("express");
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const app = express();
app.listen(9999, () => {
  console.log("started");
});
function getCurrentJobs() {
  return new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
    exec("lpstat", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("An error occurred : " + `${error}`);
        rejects(error);
      } else if (stderr) {
        console.log("An error occurred : " + `${stderr}`);
        rejects(stderr);
      }
      const currentJobs = `${stdout}`;
      console.log(currentJobs);
      resolve(currentJobs);
    });
  });
}

app.get("/currentJobs", async (req, res) => {
  const currentJobs = await getCurrentJobs();
  res.status(200).send(currentJobs);
  console.log(currentJobs);
});
```

Try using this, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to return a promise otherwise getCurrentJobs() is not returning anything

```html
const express = require("express");
const { exec } = require("child_process");

function getCurrentJobs() {
  return new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
    exec("lpstat", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("An error occurred : " + `${error}`);
        rejects(error);
      } else if (stderr) {
        console.log("An error occurred : " + `${stderr}`);
        rejects(stderr);
      }
      const currentJobs = `${stdout}`;
      console.log(currentJobs);
      resolve(currentJobs);
    });
  });
}

app.get("/currentJobs", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const currentJobs = await getCurrentJobs();
    console.log(currentJobs);
  }
  catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }

});
```